# multiple click open multiple share screens while loading first share screen

Tags: flutter, dart

I applied share package to share some data  I want to show a loader while opening share screen in android and IoS. if user click multiple times before showing share screen it open multiple share screen.

```
ListTile(
                title: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.thumbs_up_down,
                      color: DrawerIconsText,
                      size: 24.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text('Share App'),
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: () =>
                    Share.share('Share this data'),
              ),
```

Comment: You want to stop opening multiple screens when continuous click of view right ?

Comment: You can add a manual throttle for this as @AnkitMahadik suggested. 
But better also write a ticket in the library GitHub

Comment: Yes Ankit Mahadik

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

you should use Statefulwidget extendtion to get solve this problem.

As example:

```
// change your class extends to Statefulwidget

bool _isShare = false;

@override
didupdatewidget(){
  // change duration time up to you
  if (_isShare) 
    new Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 400), () {
      setState(()=> _isShare = false);
    });
}

ListTile(
                title: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Icon(
                      Icons.thumbs_up_down,
                      color: DrawerIconsText,
                      size: 24.0,
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Text('Share App'),
                  ],
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  if (!_isShare) Share.share('Share this data');
                  setState(() = _isShare = true)
                },
              ),
```

Comment: in such a way user will be able to multiple clicks on button I actually want to show a loader for the time while loading the screen.